# How do I combine a dictionary key (tuple) and its value together into one string?

Tags: python

I currently have the dictionary:

```
matrix = {(0, 0): 1, (1, 1): 1, (2, 2): 1}
```

And I need to create a single string that displays:

```
(0,0,1),(1,1,1),(2,2,1)
```

**How can I join the dictionary keys (tuples) and value together into one string?**

---

I was thinking of putting the keys into a list and adding the key into the list, but I am not entirely sure how to add it in the right order given that tuples are immutable.

```
result = []
for i, j in matrix.items():
   result.append(i)

for i in result:
```

Comment: Please include code that you have attempted first, so we can know where you are stuck

Comment: are you sure you want the result to be a string? or a list of tuples?

Answer (score 1):

The basic operation you're looking for is:

```
[k + (v,) for k, v in matrix.items()]
```

To print that in your specific way, you probably want:

```
print(', '.join(str(k + (v,)) for k, v in matrix.items()))
```

Note that dictionaries are unordered, so the order of the result is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach will keep them in the right order. The only thing it looks like you need to change in your code is splitting the tuple into its sub-parts:

```
>>> result = []
>>> for (x, y), z in matrix.items():
        result.append((x, y, z))

>>> print result
[(0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1)]
```

Comment: Note that you could give names to the individual elements and avoid indexing entirely with nested unpacking: `for (x, y), z in matrix.items(): result.append((x, y, z))` (obviously, self-documenting names are preferred, not just anonymous single-letter names).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is the most pythonic solution but try this:

```
str(tuple(_ + (matrix[_],) for _ in matrix))
```

Comment: I admit your desired string is in brackets, so I'll probably delete this answer. However, as this in my opinion is a straightforward approach, I'll leave the answer a bit if it is of use to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that your keys are `tuples` which are immutable so cannot be modified, so you need to unpack them first and then join with the dictionary value.

You can use,

```
matrix = {(0, 0): 1, (1, 1): 1, (2, 2): 1}

# *k unpack keys
print(','.join("({},{},{})".format(*k,v) for k,v in matrix.items()))
# output,
# (0,0,1),(1,1,1),(2,2,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off your work so far:

```
lst = []
for i,j in matrix.items():
  lst.append((i[0],i[1],j))
result = ",".join( repr(e) for e in lst )
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use `%s`:

```
print(','.join(["(%s,%s,%s)"%(*k,v) for k,v in matrix.items()]))
```

Or:

```
 print(','.join([str((*k,v)) for k,v in matrix.items()]))
```

Or if version not above python 3.5:

```
print(','.join(["(%s,%s,%s)"%k+(v,) for k,v in matrix.items()]))
```

Or:

```
print(','.join([str(k+(v,)) for k,v in matrix.items()]))
```